# How to rethrow an error in R?

Tags: r, error-handling, try-catch

I'll catch an error using [`tryCatch`](https://docs.tibco.com/pub//enterprise-runtime-for-R/1.5.0_may_2013/TERR_1.5.0_LanguageRef/base/conditions.html), and attempt to handle the error. However, how can I rethrow the error if I cannot handle the error locally (i.e. delegate to error handlers of parent functions higher up in the call stack)?

I tried using [`signalCondition`](https://docs.tibco.com/pub//enterprise-runtime-for-R/1.5.0_may_2013/TERR_1.5.0_LanguageRef/base/conditions.html) but instead of seeing the rethrown error, all I see is `NULL`:

```
> error.can.be.handled <- function(e) F
> 
> foo <- function() stop("foo stop!")
> tryCatch(foo(),
+   error = function(e) {
+       if (error.can.be.handled(e)) {
+           # handle error
+       }
+       else
+           signalCondition(e) # Rethrow error
+   }
+ )
NULL  # I expected to see 'Error in foo() : foo stop!' here
```

What's going wrong?

Comment: @Martin Morgan has the correct answer, though to add some more details, your version doesn't work because `stop`, in addition to signaling a condition, also outputs an error message, and aborts execution by invoking the abort restart.  So the visible "error" isn't actually anything to do with a default error handler, it's just the code in `stop`, which is why you need to call `stop` to get that to happen and signaling condition is not enough.  See `stop` source for details.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
tryCatch(stop("oops"), error=function(e) stop(e))
```

will re-signal the stop condition, although the context has been lost

```
> tryCatch(stop("oops"), error=function(e) stop(e))
Error in doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) : oops
> traceback()
5: stop(e)
4: value[[3L]](cond)
3: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
2: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
1: tryCatch(stop("oops"), error = function(e) stop(e))
> tryCatch(stop("oops"))
Error in tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers) : oops
> traceback()
3: stop("oops")
2: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
1: tryCatch(stop("oops"))
```

Returning just `e` as @tonytonov suggests does signal that a condition has occurred, but not that an error has occurred.

Comment: If you wish to retain the context, use `withCallingHandlers` instead of `tryCatch`.

Answer (score 0):

There's a workaround you can use to avoid having to catch and re-throw the error at all. Basically, use a success flag with an `on.exit` handler to run a block of code only if the code in question fails:

```
foo <- function() stop("foo stop!")
runFoo <- function() {
    success <- FALSE
    on.exit({
        if (!success) {
            ## Handle failure
        }
    })
    result <- foo()
    success <- TRUE
    result
}
runFoo()
```

The main disadvantage of this approach is that while you know an error occurred (because `success` never got set to TRUE), you don't get access to the error object itself, so you will need to use some other method to detect whether you can handle the error or not.

The `runFoo` wrapper function is needed because the `on.exit` expression runs when exiting the current function, so it needs to be run inside a function. If the code that you're writing is already inside a function, then you don't need to use this wrapper.

Answer (score -1):

There is no need in signalCondition() whatsoever:

```
tryCatch(foo(),
    error = function(e) {
        if (error.can.be.handled(e)) {
            # handle error
        }
        else
            e # Rethrow error
    }
  )

<simpleError in foo(): foo stop!>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this example simply *returns* the error object `e` rather than throwing it. Notice that your example would run silently if wrapped inside another function, whereas a rethrown error would still halt execution and print `Error in foo() : foo stop!`

Comment: Ah, right. Martin's answer is correcting this: stop(e) is actually doing the job.